# how to deploy war(spring app) on Tomcat from intelij idea?

Tags: spring, tomcat

There is application on spring.

Result of build procedure is creation of war file.

When I deploy on local tomcat, everything ok

When try to deploy to remote machine - there is error running remote.

my pom.xml file is:

```
...
    <groupId>myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data>2.0.10.RELEASE</spring.data>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <mysql.version>5.1.29</mysql.version>
        <hb.enity.manager>5.3.6.Final</hb.enity.manager>
        <hb.core>5.3.6.Final</hb.core>
        <jackson.xml>2.9.7</jackson.xml>
        <jackson.core>2.9.6</jackson.core>

        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SERVLET-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JACKSON AND XML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.core}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.xml}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hb.core}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hb.enity.manager}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My intelij idea customizations are:
[image]

Is there any addition configs for idea or may be from remote tomcat?

Comment: "When try to deploy to remote machine - there is error running remote" whats the error?

Comment: @Amogh unable to connect to the - server url

Comment: If you have complete server log (catalina log) then please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

there is information step by step